# Snowflake Database: Want to use value from a column in a table as a column name in select statement for another table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflake

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1(TBLNM varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216) not null
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
$$

var sql_cmd = "SELECT col1 FROM TBLNM ;
var ins = `insert into tabl2 (column1) SELECT  :1
      FROM table1 `
;

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
         {
         sqlText: sql_cmd
         }
      );
  var res = stmt.execute(); 
  
  while (res.next())  {
       var column1 = res.getColumnValue(1);
   
   ins_stmt=snowflake.execute(
                {
                sqlText: ins, 
                binds: [column1]                
                }
                );   
   }
 
$$
```

### for eg in TBLNM i have 3 rows values like
col1

1. name
2. lastname
3. Grade

and what i am trying here is , the value 'name' from TBLNM should be treated as column name in select statement of table 1 to fetch the values

insert into tabl2 (column1) SELECT  name FROM table1.

### this should insert name of person in table like :
column1

1. Peter
2. Parker
3. 5th

but it is inserting 'name' as a value. It is treating 'name' as a text.

### column1

Name
Lastname
Grade

Please help me out to treat bind variable as column name rather then a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript concatenation rather than bind variables.

This works for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1(TBL_NAME varchar, COL_NAME varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216) not null
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
  $$
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
     {
      sqlText: `SELECT ` + COL_NAME + ` FROM ` + TBL_NAME
     });
   var res = stmt.execute(); 

   while (res.next())  {
    var column1 = res.getColumnValue(1);
    var ins_stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
     {
      sqlText: `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT ` + column1 + ` FROM table1`
    });
    var res_ins = ins_stmt.execute(); 
   }
  $$;
call test1('store', 'col1');
```

Some examples also present here:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Snowflake-Introduces-Javascript-Stored-Procedures

Regards,